# How is the maildir for each user supposed to be created?

Tags: postfix, email-server

I've installed postfix+dovecot under ubuntu and got permission errors when receiving mail:

```
Nov 10 22:04:08 amalthea postfix/local[14942]: warning: maildir access problem for UID/GID=9999/9999: create maildir file /var/mail/skyking/tmp/1447189448.P14942.amalthea: Permission denied
Nov 10 22:04:08 amalthea postfix/local[14942]: warning: perhaps you need to create the maildirs in advance
```

This was solved by simply creating the directory `/var/mail/skyking` (with permissions `drwxr-sr-x`).

How was the directory `/var/mail/skyking` supposed to be created? I mean it's not feasible to manually create a new directory for each user.

Note: I use LDAP for user accounts so creating users don't need to happen on the mail server. Also mail is read on another computer via IMAP.

Comment: Why are your Maildir folders under `/var/mail`?  AFAIK most people put them under `/home/`?    `I mean it's not feasible to manually create a new directory for each user.`  Not that it should be required, but why isn't it feasible?  Write a script with a LDAP query that finds new created accounts, then make the directory.

Comment: Postfix (or, rather, the MDA that Postfix calls out to) always makes the maildir for me.

Comment: @Zoredache The reason I don't want it under `/home` is that there is no other reason why the user would have a home directory and in any case it would result in the same problem - then instead the home directory of the user has to be created instead of a directory under `/var/mail`.

Answer (score 0):

Does postfix have the right to create the maildir? Check that the user shown by `ls -ld /var/mail` is the same as that shown by `ls -l /var/mail/skyking`.

Comment: I'm not at the location now so I can't check, but the `/var/mail/skyking` is owned by `skyking:mail`. At least that (uid) is not the same as `/var/mail`. What permissions should `/var/mail` have? I'd guess `???rws???` (and have the `mail` group) and I suppose that the program runs as `<user>:mail`.

Comment: `/var/mail/skyking` is owned by `skyking:mail` because you created it that way :) But yes, there is a problem. You have two options: either postfix delivery runs as root and can create a directory owned by `user:mail`, or else delivery creates files owned by say `mail:mail` and dovecot reads those. If this is just a server with no "real" users on it, I recommend the second option ("virtual" users), but in any case postfix and dovecot need to use the same option.